# No disk space confusion

Tags: kde, disk-usage

I am trying to install kde on ubuntu server, when i run `apt-get install kubuntu-desktop` the `cp` command says I have no space:
Complete output of the above command: [here](http://wikisend.com/download/275680/log.txt)

[image]

[image: df -i output]

[image: I ahve]

Other info: The os runs on an ESX server.

Comment: @AvinashRaj can you elaborate on that, do you have a solution?

Comment: post only the command which results in the output shown in the 1st screenshot.

Comment: apt-get install kubuntu-desktop this is the command

Comment: The command tries to create temporary files in /tmp directory, which is full, I need a bigger one.

Comment: You don't strictly speaking need a separate partition for the `/tmp` directory. You have plenty of space on `/`, so I would just use that. Can you try to issue the command: `sudo umount /tmp`, then try again to `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`?

Comment: You're welcome :) To make those changes permanent, remove the line that mentions `/tmp` from your `/etc/fstab` file. Cheers!